# Why this " (one symbol) works as one double quote as well

Tags: punctuation

According all the tutorials I could found, I need to use

```
`` + ''    (two single quote symbol)
```

to produce the double quote. However, it seems that

```
`` + "     (one symbol)
```

works as well.

Is this supposed to be? If so, why none of tutorials mention this?

Comment: There are various ways to create the quotes (I personally use the csquotes package). Your second solution will not work with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` so it is not recommended. `”` will work if you use the correct inputenc option.

Comment: All tutorials explain that the closing double quotes should be input as `''` and they are right. Inputting `"` has unpredictable output.

Comment: there are technical reasons for this ``...'' stuff, but they're buried in the history of knuth's font mechanisms.  much of the time, we don't use knuth's original font mechanisms, nowadays, but the silly typing rules have persisted.  :-(  ... and the tutorials probably ought to mention it, but the authors probably thought it wasn't worth mentioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `"` seems to produce the right quotes, but this is not really true. There are two cases.

### OT1 encoding

Look at what happens with these apparently identical inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

this ends a quotation." And here text starts again

this ends a quotation.'' And here text starts again

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you spot the difference? In the first case a normal interword space is produced after the quotes, in the second case there's an extended space, which is what's expected after a period (preceding or not the quotes), of course assuming "non French spacing".

### T1 encoding

Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the input above and you get

[image]

The problem with the extended space *seems* to have disappeared, but this is not true: the fact is that the glyph produced by `"` is wider than the curly double quotes. But it's even worse than before, because now the quotes are straight and not curly, which is unacceptable from a typographycal point of view.

### Conclusion

All tutorials recommend `''` for producing closing double quotes and they are fully right.

Comment: Why don't you get the sentence-ending space when you type `... quotation." And ...`? Just wondering.

Comment: @MSC Because the space factor code of `"` is not zero. One *could* set it to zero, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing it out. Here's one MWE to illustrate the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for latex
% \usepackage{fontspec} % for xetex
\begin{document}
{\Huge "hello"\par}

{\Huge ``hello"\par}

{\Huge ``hello''\par}

\end{document}
```

The following is the output.
[image]

If we don't use `fontenc` or `fontspec`, (which is highly recommend against), all three of them give correct result for right quote, shown following:

[image]

## Conclusion

Use what's mentioned in all the tutorials, and include `fontenc` or `fontspec`.

Comment: Does the first one give a correct result for you?

Comment: @karlkoeller What do you mean by "first one"? The two images for corresponding to two use cases, the one with `fontenc` and the one without `fontenc`.

Comment: The first one of the second image. Is it a wanted behavior?

Comment: @karlkoeller obviously not - but the question implies that Albert is aware of that :) so I think this is just an example for demonstration purposes

Comment: @cgnieder Yes I know, I was only kidding :-)