# Straight quotes in tabbing

Tags: tabbing

I need to display source code using the tabbing environment and \sffamily. (Please note that I cannot use neither listings nor verbatim since I cannot dynamically set my tab stops).

I defined an environment sftabbing for doing this. A Minimal Working Example is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
  {\par\sffamily\small\tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES ('Federal Express', '02 752 75 75') \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName='Fedex' \\
WHERE \> CompanyName='Federal Express' \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = 'Germany' AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}

\end{document}
```

However, in this case the quotes are transformed into curly quotes and I would need they remain straight quotes. How to achieve this ?

I know that the package upquote achieve this for the verbatim environment.

By the way, is there any way to improve the definition of my environment so that I do not need to write `\\` to change lines ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `textcomp` that has a straight quote glyph and locally activate the quote character so that it produces that glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
 {\par
  % locally define the active quote
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`' \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\textquotesingle
  % locally activate the quote
  \catcode`'=\active
  \sffamily\small\tabbing}
 {\endtabbing\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES ('Federal Express', '02 752 75 75') \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName='Fedex' \\
WHERE \> CompanyName='Federal Express' \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = 'Germany' AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For double quotes the best is to do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

so that `"` will do by itself. However, if you have reasons not to do it, here's a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc} % keep OT1 as default
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
 {\par
  % locally define the active quote
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`' \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\textquotesingle
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`" \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\textquotedbl}}
  % locally activate the quote
  \catcode`'=\active \catcode`"=\active
  \sffamily\small\tabbing}
 {\endtabbing\par}

\begin{document}

Quotes: "

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES ('Federal Express', "02 752 75 75") \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName='Fedex' \\
WHERE \> CompanyName='Federal Express' \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = 'Germany' AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that using `"` for getting curly closing quotes is disputable to begin with. See [Why this " (one symbol) works as one double quote as well](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121156/)

Comment: Many thanks! This is indeed what I needed. But I would need the same behaviour for the double quotes. How to extend your definition ? I know the T1 font enconding provides the \textquotedbl character.

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi If you have nothing that prevents `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, this would be sufficient: using `"` would produce straight quotes.

Comment: Alas, I would need this behaviour only within the tabbing environment, otherwise I would need to change all the 650+ pages of my manuscript looking for " (one double quote) and replacing them by '' (two single quotes)

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi Using `"` for producing closing double quotes is wrong to begin with. See [Why this one symbol `"` works as one double quote as well](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121156/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`upquote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/upquote) package with `\textquotesingle`. Since it's rather cumbersome to type `\textquotesingle` I usually define a shorter command, such as the `\upsq` one in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upquote}

\newcommand*{\upsq}[1]{\textquotesingle #1\textquotesingle}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
  {\par\sffamily\small\tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES (\upsq{Federal Express}, \upsq{02 752 75 75}) \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName=\upsq{Fedex} \\
WHERE \> CompanyName=\upsq{Federal Express} \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = \upsq{Germany} AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of result]

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs of `upquote` package indicates that, for the standard CM fonts, a `\ttfamily\char13` already produces the desired glyph, so I just made the `'` active and redefined it.

EDITED so that straight quote is only active in the `sftabbing` environment, and restores to normal quote thereafter.

EDITED to include `cmap` package which allows proper cut/paste of quote character from PDF (see [Can't copy-paste from my PDF. Any idea why?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72900/cant-copy-paste-from-my-pdf-any-idea-why))

ADDENDUM added for those for whom `cmap` approach does not work.

```
\RequirePackage{cmap}
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{sftabbing}
  {\par\sffamily\small\squoteon\tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\squoteoff\par}

\let\svquote'
\catcode`'=\active
\def\squoteon{\catcode`'=\active%
  \def'{\setbox0=\hbox{\ttfamily\char13}\raisebox{1pt}{\box0}}}
\def\squoteoff{\catcode`'=12\let\'\svquote}
\catcode`'=12

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES ('Federal Express', '02 752 75 75') \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName='Fedex' \\
WHERE \> CompanyName='Federal Express' \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = 'Germany' AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}
Test's of quote
\end{document}
```

Zoom:

[image]

For comparison, the straight quote activated by the `textcomp` package *in `\sffamily`* looks like a rectangular block, which may be more in keeping with the sf style, but which I find unattractive:

[image]

I thus chose to retain the `\ttfamily` look for the quote character.

---

ADDENDUM:

For those for whom the `cmap` package does not provide relief for the copy/paste feature from PDFs, an alternative "glyph-to-unicode" approach is here.  Both methods work for me, but the OP was having difficulty with the `cmap` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{sftabbing}
  {\par\sffamily\small\squoteon\tabbing}
  {\endtabbing\squoteoff\par}

\let\svquote'
\catcode`'=\active
\def\squoteon{\catcode`'=\active%
  \def'{\setbox0=\hbox{\ttfamily\char13}\raisebox{1pt}{\box0}}}
\def\squoteoff{\catcode`'=12\let\'\svquote}
\catcode`'=12

\pdfgentounicode=1 %
\input glyphtounicode.tex %

\begin{document}

\begin{sftabbing}
INSERT \= INTO Shippers(CompanyName, Phone) \\
\> VALUES ('Federal Express', '02 752 75 75') \\ \\
UPDATE \= Shippers \\
SET \> CompanyName='Fedex' \\
WHERE \> CompanyName='Federal Express' \\ \\
SELECT \> ProductID, ProductName \\
FROM \> Products P \\
WHERE \> EXISTS ( \\
\> SELECT \= * \\
\> FROM \> Orders O JOIN Customers C ON \\
\> \> O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID JOIN \\
\> \> OrderDetails D ON O.OrderID = D.OrderID \\
\> WHERE \> C.Country = 'Germany' AND D.ProductID = P.ProductID )
\end{sftabbing}
Test's of quote
\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on your idea, I improved your solution to be able to have the same behaviour for double quotes.

Comment: A minor problem is that when I copy/paste from the resulting pdf I obtain additional spaces as in SET CompanyName= ' Fedex ' instead of SET CompanyName='Fedex' and the former is incorrect in SQL. This will prevent readers to copy/paste the code from the manuscript and test it directly on the computer.

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi Please see revision.  Package `cmap` was required.

Comment: The package cmap does not solve the problem :-( A possible diagnostics is that 

\begin{tabbing}
\raisebox{1pt}{\ttfamily\char13}Blah blah\raisebox{1pt}{\ttfamily\char13}
\end{tabbing}

produces the output 'Blah blah' when I copy/paste from the pdf file, while

\begin{sftabbing}
\raisebox{1pt}{\ttfamily\char13}Blah blah\raisebox{1pt}{\ttfamily\char13}
\end{sftabbing}

produces the output ' Blah blah ' (with extra spaces) when I copy/paste from the pdf file.

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi  Using Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader, my copy paste works fine on this code.  Perhaps one should check if packages are up to date.

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi See addendum, for alternative approach.