# How do I change all curly single and double quote marks to basic ascii ' and " quotes?

Tags: unicode, quotation, ascii

I noticed XeLaTeX uses different unicode such as the [SINGLE RIGHT QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) (and related others), and for hyphens too. How can I get it to just use `'` and `"` and `-` regular ascii marks like you use for programming, so (a) when you copy-paste the stuff from the PDF it doesn't use the special unicode characters for quotations/hyphens, and (b) I don't have to write `\regularsinglequote` or something like that for every quote I want to use, I can just write a sentence `"hello world, I don't use unicode quotes-or-hyphens"` and it uses the plain ascii versions of quotes/hyphens.

The document I'm using is basically this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=black,
  filecolor=black,
  linkcolor=black,
  urlcolor=black
}
\setmainfont{MyMonospaceFont}
\newlength{\characterwidth}
\settowidth{\characterwidth}{\normalfont x}
\geometry{margin=0.7in,textwidth=96\characterwidth,lines=48}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright\setlength{\parindent}{3\characterwidth}}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
\title{xyz}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section*{A}
hello world
\section*{B}
\section*{C}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a small complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172826/straight-quotes-in-tabbing, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204261/how-can-i-get-straight-quotes-in-pseudocode, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436308/changing-all-single-quotes-to-be-straight-when-within-texttt

Comment: Disable `Ligatures=TeX` for your monospaced font

Comment: How to do that? `\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}`

Comment: by default the quotes work as expected for the typewriter font, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnIJv.png. So show an example instead of letting us guess what your document is doing and which font you actually want to change.

Comment: The font I am using is [this](https://github.com/7-rabbit/source/blob/master/sketch/font.ttf).

Comment: Don't link to external sites. I have neither the will nor the time to follow such links.

Comment: You just asked for the font that I was using, it's not a publicly available font...

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the replacement of the quotes and dashes with the option [Ligatures=TeXReset]:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Ligatures=TeXReset]

\begin{document}
"abc--cde 'quote' text"
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get `LaTeX error: "kernel/key-choice-unknown" ! Key 'fontspec/Ligatures' accepts only a fixed set of choices.`

Comment: then  either update your texsystem or check the fontspec documentation or the code for the name your version used.